GET request for an API regarding phone transcripts
I am trying to write a program that will fetch a transcript of phone records from a data base but my code keeps giving me a 401.  I am pretty sure I have the url correct, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class TranscriptService
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://commcenterdev.azurewebsites.net/phoneCalls/";

        // Replace with your actual API Key and Tenant ID.
        string callId = "CALL_ID_HERE";
        string apiKey = "API_KEY_HERE";
        string tenantId = "TENANT_ID_HERE";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Set the required headers.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("phoneCalls", callId);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("API-Key", apiKey);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Tenant-Id", tenantId);

                // Send a GET request to the specified URL.
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                // Ensure the request was successful.
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                // Read the response content as a string.
                string transcript = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Output the content to the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Transcript:");
                Console.WriteLine(transcript);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occurred during the request.
                Console.WriteLine("Error fetching the transcript: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

I am quite new at C# so I don't understand too much but it seems like the code
takes the base url, callId, api key, and tenant id and creates a new https request.  It then sends it to the web and waits for the request to be successfull or if not, will catch the exception and output a message.  Please let me know if I have this correct.
I simply enter the callId, apiKey, and tenantId in the strings, but it just returns a 401.

Several possible causes: (1) apiKey is wrong, (2) header name used for apiKey is wrong, (3) apiKey was created for a different server than the one you are talking to, (4) apiKey has been revoked - and there could be other causes like the server behaving incorrectly (it looks like a DEV server; so who made it, what problems could it have?)

@PeterB by header name, do you mean the quoted part of client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("", ); ?

Yes that is what I mean.
